# Which coordinate system to use for Excel's 3D Map?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, 3d

I have tables from GIS software that I'd like to use with the 3D map function in  Excel (so that my coworkers who don't use GIS can see the maps). The tables don't have address/name info that the built-in bing search engine can retreive geographic info from, but it does have XYZ coordinates. However, the points end up in completely wrong places on the world map. I cannot find out which coordinate system Excel is using, I've tried the elimination process so far, but I hope someone has the answer for this.

Also, when I've selected the X and Y fields in the table as X and Y coordinate fields, respectively, why do I have to select one of them for visualization? The X is no good without the Y and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: 3D maps only support WGS 1984 coordinates, it seems to work when I convert my data to this system.

The answer was found here: https://sway.com/H7uaa8hs8betQKoJ